# Assigning Javascript array value to Json Object for CanvasXpress

Tags: javascript, json

I want to know which is the best place to get some help with CanvasXpress. I can't see any threads here in the forum. I am actually using CanvasXpress to display some dynamic data and I understand that canvasXpress accepts it as a json object. My problem is that I am building a heatmap and when I assign the vars: and smps: variables as well as the data: variable with my javascript array variables it doesn't create a proper json object and either returns an error or the page simply does not load. I have the javascript array as follows: var axis = 'A2', 'A3', 'A20', 'A6', 'A10', 'A17', 'A7', 'A19', 'A11', 'A12', 'A9', 'C2', 'C7', 'C29', 'C24' which is same for both vars: and smps: and for data: variable I have a javascript array which is basically a twodimensional array like this 
                          matrix =  [0.00, 0.33, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33, 0.33, 0.00],
                                           [0.33, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33, 0.00, 0.00, 0.33],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                                           [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]

But, I am unable to assign these javascript variables inside the json object below:

```
   var cx = new CanvasXpress('canvas1',
                              {y: {vars: axis,
                               smps:  axis,
                               desc:  ['Intensity'],
                               data:  [matrix]}},
                              {graphType: 'Heatmap',
                               showDataValues: true,
                               background: 'rgb(245,245,245)',
                               indicatorCenter: 'rainbow',
                               heatmapType: 'green',
                              // gradient: true,
                               centerData: true,
                               indicatorWidth: 8});
```

Can you please help me with this or forward me to a forum where I can get help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a square bracket issue. try something like this:

```
remoteData = [
    [10,12,153,4,100,73,42,64],
    [12,4,60,5,24,14,32,13],
    [7,12,20,13,49,52,42,92],
    [21,10,30,8,65,2000,47,58],
    [15,14,100,5,34,130,82,51],
    [100,82,73,124,0,4,5,142],
    [100,82,73,124,0,4,5,142]
];             

newData = {
    "y": {
        "vars": ["Gene1","Gene2","Gene3","Gene4","Gene5","Gene6","Gene7"],
        "smps": ["Smp1","Smp2","Smp3","Smp4","Smp5","Smp6","Smp7","Smp8"],
        "desc": ["Intensity"],
        "data": remoteData
    }
};
```

[full working example](http://pastebin.com/GJmLiPYm)